# Docusign calculated fields checked/greyed out

Tags: docusignapi

I am a developer using the Docusign API. When my users are tagging signature spots for their signers, I have disabled as many "tag types" as I can except for just SIGNATURE, INITIAL, FIRST/LAST NAME. However the users appear to have this "Formula" tag they can add which is of no use to us. I don't want it because it can confuse our users, but when I log into my account under Preferences/Features the "Enable Calculated Fields" checkbox is checked but greyed out so i cannot uncheck it.

I've looked at the Documentation and haven't figured out why this would be greyed out. There is no mention of this feature being tied to another feature. Is there any way to the formula/calculated-field tags?

Answer (score 2):

Please ask either DocuSign Customer Service or your Account Manager for help to get this resolved. This is an account setting issue that probably needs to be updated on the platform for your account.